# Regex in javascript with group unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex

here's the code:

```
reg = /(\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}/;
var str8 = "111.222.333.444";
console.log(str8.match(reg));
```

the result:Array [ "111.222.333.444", "333." ]
test in firefox

the first result I can expect but what I can't expect is the second result.
can anyone tell me why it get second result and tell me how to fix to get only 
the first one.

thanks~!

Comment: it's because capturing group, avoid that by non-capturing group add `?:` ,`/(?:\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}/;`

Comment: Use non-capturing group: `(?:\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing groups appear in [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) (without `/g` modifier) results as parts of the resulting array.

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

And [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) help says:

> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, **and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured**.

To get rid of them, just replace capturing groups with non-capturing ones:

```js
reg = /(?:\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}/;
//      ^^
var str8 = "111.222.333.444";
console.log(str8.match(reg));
```

Result: `["111.222.333.444", index: 0, input: "111.222.333.444"]`.